# PHP mail attachment with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I would like to send email from Codeigniter mail class, with attachment img and img in mail body.

```
$this->email->from('office@office.com', 'Email');
$this->email->to('aaa@aaa.com');

$this->email->attach('pic.png');        

$this->email->set_mailtype("html");

$this->email->subject('Email');
$this->email->message('<img src="??????" />');  

$this->email->send();
```

Img was send in attachment but not in body mail. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do it... You need to specify the attachment as "inline", then use the image in the body.

```
$this->email->attach('pic.png', 'inline');
$this->email->message('<img src="cid:pic.png"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching image, instead linking it in HTML message. Try to put fully qualified image link inside image `src` attribute.

Comment: The defeats the whole purpose in attaching the file!

Comment: Yes, but with this purpose almost **any** email client will view image (with some restrictions of course).

Answer (score 0):

To send an image in the body of the email, create a html file and put that as a message.

```
$message = $this->load->view('view_file_name','',TRUE);

$this->email->message($message);
```